# How can we relate the screens in Liferay with the existing jsp pages

Tags: liferay-6

I am new to Liferay .
Please excuse if this is a dumb Question .

For example please see the below screen shot (new user registration screen)

[image]

How can we know that the screen belongs to create_account.jsp into html/portlet/login

Is there any thumb rule to relate screens to jsp pages ??

Comment: one way is atleast you can identify the modules, portlet, portal etc from the pages. page name can also give hint sometimes which module or jsp it can refer, other way is from firebug you find a particular form element search for the name in source/jsp in eclipse or IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find liferay portlet that you need in liferay's WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml (in source that would be portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml). Take note of `<struts-path>`.

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>58</portlet-name>
    <icon>/html/icons/login.png</icon>
    <struts-path>login</struts-path>
    <configuration-action-class>com.liferay.portlet.login.action.ConfigurationActionImpl</configuration-action-class>
    <preferences-owned-by-group>true</preferences-owned-by-group>
    <use-default-template>false</use-default-template>
    <private-request-attributes>false</private-request-attributes>
    <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>
    <render-weight>50</render-weight>
    <header-portlet-css>/html/portlet/login/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <css-class-wrapper>portlet-login</css-class-wrapper>
    <add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>
</portlet>
```

Now open stuts-config.xml (from same location) and find `<action>` which path contains value from previous step (**login**) and continuing with action in question (**/login/create_account**). Take note of name/path attribute.

```
<action path="/login/create_account" type="com.liferay.portlet.login.action.CreateAccountAction">
    <forward name="portlet.login.create_account" path="portlet.login.create_account" />
    <forward name="portlet.login.login" path="portlet.login.login" />
    <forward name="portlet.login.update_account" path="portlet.login.update_account" />
</action>
```

Finally open tiles-defs.xml (from same location) and find  `<definition>` which has name from previous step (**portlet.login.create_account**)

```
<definition name="portlet.login.create_account" extends="portlet.login">
    <put name="portlet_content" value="/portlet/login/create_account.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir , it was very clear and very informative .

Comment: Don't mention it, I'm glad it was helpful